How to install google protobuf module on distroless image?
This is my Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12-slim AS build-env

WORKDIR /usr/

COPY . /usr/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install libodbc2 -y
    
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -v
    
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian12
COPY --from=build-env /usr/ /usr/

WORKDIR /usr/
    
CMD ["/usr/main.py"]

requirements.txt file contents:
google==3.0.0
protobuf>=4.25,<5.0

I have tried out several options but I get error saying:

google.protobuf no such module named google.


This question is similar to: ImportError: No module named google.protobuf. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I suspect the asker is looking for a more Docker-specific answer.  /usr is a system directory that contains a lot of things (a large part of what a Linux distribution brings is in there) and you probably don't want to install your application there.  Does, say, this recipe to create a virtual environment work better?

According to this answer to the dupe, the google package (which is not authored by Google) causes a namespace collision with some Google-authored packages. IMHO, the problem is unrelated to Docker and the solution is to remove google from requirements.txt. Does the problem go away when you run outside of Docker?
